# Error matching with ORB in Android

Tags: android, opencv

My code is working good but when it extracts keypoints, it matches poorly the two images.
Here you can find my code, but I don't know how to draw good matched in `JAVA Android`

```
 descriptors = new Mat();
        keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
        detector.detect(img1, keypoints);
        descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
        descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints, descriptors);
        matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
     ColorDetection.cvt_YUVtoRGBtoHSV(mYuv,mGraySubmat);
          MatOfKeyPoint mKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfDMatch  matches = new MatOfDMatch();

          detector.detect(mGraySubmat, mKeyPoints);
          descriptor.compute(mGraySubmat, mKeyPoints, mIntermediateMat);

        matcher.match(mIntermediateMat,descriptors,matches);
        mIntermediateMat2.create(resultSize, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints, mGraySubmat, mKeyPoints, matches, 
                mIntermediateMat2,GREEN, RED,  MATCH_MASK, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

          Imgproc.resize(mIntermediateMat2, mIntermediateMat2, mRgba.size());
          Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat2, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA, 4);
     Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);

      DMatch dm[] = matches.toArray();
          List<Point> lp1 = new ArrayList<Point>(dm.length);
          List<Point> lp2 = new ArrayList<Point>(dm.length);
          KeyPoint tkp[] = keypoints.toArray();
          KeyPoint qkp[] = mKeyPoints.toArray();
          for (int i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
              DMatch dma = dm[i];
              lp1.add(tkp[dma.trainIdx].pt);
              lp2.add(qkp[dma.queryIdx].pt);
          }
          MatOfPoint2f pointsPrev = new MatOfPoint2f(lp1.toArray(new Point[0]));
          MatOfPoint2f pointsAct  = new MatOfPoint2f(lp2.toArray(new Point[0]));
        Log.i("pointsPrev", pointsPrev.size().toString());
        Log.i("pointsAct", pointsAct.size().toString());
          fundamental_matrix.create(resultSize, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        fundamental_matrix = Calib3d.findFundamentalMat(
                  pointsAct, pointsPrev, Calib3d.FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99);
```

any suggestion?

**EDIT :**

i can't convert matches to list ! because `Feature2d.drawMatches()`
need a `MatOfDmatch` and not a `List<Dmatch>`

```
MatOfDMatch matches, matches12, matches21;
matcher.match( descriptors1, descriptors2, matches12 );
matcher.match( descriptors2, descriptors1, matches21 );

iterate matches12
    DMatch forward = matches12[i];  
    DMatch backward = matches21[forward.trainIdx]; 
    if( backward.trainIdx == forward.queryIdx ) 
 //add forward to matches 
Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints, mGraySubmat, mKeyPoints, matches,mIntermediateMat2);
```

Comment: can you please fix the indentation of the code?

Comment: This code is used to extract the key points of the two images using ORB the target is  I want to extract the good matching and draw it
just all

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Your code should be like this:**

```
 FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
 DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);;
 DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

 //first image
 Mat img1 = Highgui.imread("<image1 path>");
 Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
 MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

 detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
 descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

 //second image
 Mat img2 = Highgui.imread("<image2 path>");
 Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
 MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

 detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
 descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

 //matcher should include 2 different image's descriptors
 MatOfDMatch  matches = new MatOfDMatch();             
 matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);
 //feature and connection colors
 Scalar RED = new Scalar(255,0,0);
 Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0);
 //output image
 Mat outputImg = new Mat();
 MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
 //this will draw all matches, works fine
 Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, 
 outputImg, GREEN, RED,  drawnMatches, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
```

Also if you want to display just features, you can add this code:

```
 Mat featuredImg = new Mat();
 Scalar kpColor = new Scalar(255,159,10);//this will be color of keypoints
 //featuredImg will be the output of first image
 Features2d.drawKeypoints(img1, keypoints1, featuredImg , kpColor, 0);
 //featuredImg will be the output of first image
 Features2d.drawKeypoints(img1, keypoints1, featuredImg , kpColor, 0);
```

Then you can show matched points like this:

```
  Bitmap imageMatched = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputImg.cols(), outputImg.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);//need to save bitmap
  Utils.matToBitmap(outputImg, imageMatched);
  ImageView.setImageBitmap(imageMatched);
```

Eventually you can implement good matches. I hope [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058435/what-to-do-with-orb-feature-matches) will be helpful.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, now i want a good condition to found a good similarity but this condition is not efficace why ?
 if(row_count>490&&good_matches.size()<60 &&min_dist<12)  logo_detected=true;
else logo_detected=false;

Comment: Your welcome.I don't want to mislead but I think it depends on what you are working on. You have to calculate for your own project.

Comment: I have used your code, and tested it with 10-12 images, but it is not giving perfect match, i just want to find the coordinates of the exact matching location but it is not able to give me the perfect result. if possible then give me the way by which i can increaser the accuracy of matching

Comment: It seems like there is a few way to increase the accuracy of matching but i do not know how to do it. Maybe there is no way it just does it its own way. Because it is native library in android. So that we can not see inside of the methods. Also i tried to use the average of the scores and i defined a threshold(it depends on what you are working on) for eliminate the bad matches.

Answer (score 5):

Good Matches method is basing on removing from your `MatOfDMatch  matches = new MatOfDMatch();` list matched points that has different descriptors or spacial location. What I suggest to do is to loop over matches list and put to the new list matches that are satisfy conditions like:

```
int DIST_LIMIT = 80;
List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
List<DMatch> matches_final= new ArrayList<DMatch>();
for(int i=0; i<matchesList.size(); i++)
   if(matchesList .get(i).distance <= DIST_LIMIT){
       matches_final.add(matches.toList().get(i));
   }
}

MatOfDMatch matches_final_mat = new MatOfDMatch();
matches_final_mat.fromList(matches_final);
```

Same thing you can do with matched points coordinates.
[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html) is the useful link.

Comment: i can't convert matches to list ! because Feature2d.drawMatches()
need a MatOfDmatch and not a List<Dmatch> 


    MatOfDMatch **matches**, matches12, matches21;
    matcher.match( descriptors1, descriptors2, matches12 );
    matcher.match( descriptors2, descriptors1, matches21 );
 // iterate matches12
        DMatch forward = matches12[i];  
        DMatch backward = matches21[forward.trainIdx]; 
        if( backward.trainIdx == forward.queryIdx ) 
        // add forward to **matches** 
Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints, mGraySubmat, mKeyPoints, **matches**,mIntermediateMat2);

Comment: You can convert it with `MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();   matches.fromList(matches_final);`. It is not so efficient, but I don't see another way ho to do Good Matches in java.

Comment: yes thnx i fixed  why ? 
and if we call  function  c++ jni?  
did you have another solution

Comment: @Andriy - What would be the best threshold for `DIST_LIMIT`?

Comment: @Torcellite I'm using 80. Note that this is a Hamming distance between matched descriptors. If you convert point's descriptor to 512bit binary string, there can be 80 different bits.

Comment: Could you take a look at this project and tell me how I would go about implementing the method to find the best matches, please? http://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator

Comment: @Torcellite inside of the compare() function, after matcher.match() at line 162 add code of my answer. I just have edited it. I also suggest to use BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING matcher. And if your images are very similar, you should use smaller DIST_LIMIT. I'm using 80, because of the noise on images

Comment: I do not know what should be to put as dist_min because my case is generic, I want to detect any object which can then be analyzed 
any help please

Comment: I suggest you to set it as 80. Then test if objects are correctly recognized. If no object recognized, increment it. If objects are incorrectly recognized then set it to lower value. It's impossible to know exact value of DIST_LIMIT. You should adjust it by yourself.

Comment: thank you its working,  is there another solution (condition) that is efficace ? 
otherwise i read some articles about the descriptors, but I have not come to understand the difference between them ORB FREAK FAST SURF ... if you have a good article that shows their  thnks

Comment: No I'm sorry, I do not know any paper which compares all this algorithms.

Comment: no problem i found one :) thanks
http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/01/comparison-of-the-opencvs-feature-detection-algorithms-2/

Comment: is it possible to track the recognized object?

Comment: Yes. Transform matches and keypoints to list `List<DMatch> matches_list = matches.toList();List<KeyPoint> kp_list = keypoints.toList();` and then iterate through the list kp_list.get(matches_list.get(i).queryIdx) and find the minimum and maximum X and Y of matched keypoints in order to encounter two points that will define your rectangle. Then define a rectangle `Rect roi = new Rect(new Point(minX,minY),new Point(maxX,maxY))` and then you can draw rectangle around matched(recognized) region. Taken from my previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16225663/548601)

Comment: @viktorovich thanks, but it can also help me to pose estimation and registration of graphical objects on the recognized objects?