# Can not match 2 descriptor opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

I try to do like this theard [Error matching with ORB in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544158/error-matching-with-orb-in-android)

But when i use matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches); My app is exit and say "Unfortumatively, Car_Traking_1 has stopped"

This is my code when i not use matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches); It's run and i can see data of descriptor1,descriptor1 in logcat

This is my code:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mImageRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(icon, img_object);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mImageRGBA,img_scene,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);


    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);;
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

    //first image
    Mat img1 = img_object;
    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    //second image
    Mat img2 = img_scene;
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    //matcher should include 2 different image's descriptors
    Log.i("aaa1", descriptors1.dump());
    Log.i("aaa2",descriptors2.dump());
    Log.i("aaa3",String.valueOf(descriptors1.cols()));
    Log.i("aaa4",String.valueOf(descriptors1.rows()));
    Log.i("aaa5",String.valueOf(descriptors2.cols()));
    Log.i("aaa6",String.valueOf(descriptors2.rows()));



    return mImageRGBA;
}
```

I see descriptor1 and descriptor2 have data, size of descriptor1 is 32x104 and size of descriptor1 is 32x219

But now when i add 2 line

```
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);
```

So my code will like

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mImageRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(icon, img_object);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mImageRGBA,img_scene,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);


    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);;
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

    //first image
    Mat img1 = img_object;
    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    //second image
    Mat img2 = img_scene;
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    //matcher should include 2 different image's descriptors
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);



    return mImageRGBA;
}
```

When i run it, it run and exit and say "Unfortumatively, Car_Traking_1 has stopped"
I don't know what problem with it, or descriptor1 and descriptor2 had to same size. How can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert your OBJECT image to gray? You converted scene photo with this code on the start of onCameraFrame:

`mImageRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
Utils.bitmapToMat(icon, img_object);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mImageRGBA,img_scene,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);`

but where did you converted object image to the same format?

Before calculating descriptor and keypoints of object image you should convert it to gray:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(OBJECT_IMAGE,img_object,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
```

Just be careful to convert object image to Mat() before using this above. If its bitmap you can convert it on the same way as you did with scene image.